# AS3 change item visibility if variable goes below X amount

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, dispatchevent, gsap

I've attached a source file below, I'm kinda stuck.

Basically, its an FLA that has a variable that changes (smscounter) based on whatever number is read in from an XML file (on my server).  There is a big movieclip called "rewinder" on frame 1 of the main stage.  There are left and right buttons that navigate between frames within that movieclip "rewinder".  What I'm trying to do in theory is:

```
if(frame != 2) {button_right.visibility = true};
if(frame == 2 && smscounter > 5) {button_right.visibility = true};
if(frame == 2 && smscounter < 5) {button_right.visibility = false}
```

I've been told that won't work simply because once a variable (visibility) is set, it's not going to just continually check it, so I have to dispatch an event?  I've tried 3-4 tutorials and I can't get any to work.

Now a few things:
 - I would LOVE to avoid anything super complicated.  All I need is on frame 2 for the button to not be there IF smscounter is below 5.  Other tutorials required another class and document class, but I couldn't get them working
 - The buttons are currently outside the rewinder movieclip.  I put them inside and on each frame, but then I couldn't get them to react to a rollover.
 - The code is about as optimized as if a first grader wrote it, mainly because I'm a designer and I've been having help along the whole way with this.
 - Greensock LoaderMax is being used to put the videos and sound in.  Not super relevant to the problem, I just left them in there to give a better picture of what I'm working on.

Link to FLA and source files:
http://www.mediafire.com/download.php?ejy6j9h9r1c1829

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can add this code to the main timeline 
looks like you can only go to frame 2 and 3, but you have a total of 21 frames (from voltagebar) that's why I used the numbers instead of 1 and totalFrames.

```
rewinder.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,checkButtons);
function checkButtons(e:Event):void{
    if(rewinder.currentFrame <= 2){
        button_left.visible = false;
    }else{
        button_left.visible = true;
    }

    if(rewinder.currentFrame >= 3){
        button_right.visible = false;
    }else{
        button_right.visible = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect, got some similar help from a friend - I just didn't know how to listen for the ENTER_FRAME and then do something.  (I'm a noob)  Thank you for the help!

Comment: if you don't need AS3 capabilities, you might want to consider using AS2 code if you're just trying to get a project done and don't have a lot of time to learn about as3. Otherwise I'd highly recommend getting a book or three on as3.

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/ASIN/059652787X/zeuslabs-20/ref=nosim/ http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/ASIN/1590598458/zeuslabs-20/ref=nosim/ http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/ASIN/0789737027/zeuslabs-20/ref=nosim/

Comment: The basics and games programming will get you through some basics and hopefully save you a lot of greif, the OOP should help you get to the next level, where you're programming, not scripting. When you're making games in as3 there is a lot of room for memory leaks to happen, which can cause flash and the browser to crash. This becomes a headache especially when you're relying on timeline animations and code.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the references.  I would have used AS2, but the only way I could load a TON of videos easily was via Greensock Loadermax.  I'm a design student, so I play around with some AS3 and other OOP languages, but I tend to get way in over my head, this project specifically.  I have the O'Reilly AS3 book but still just learning at my slow pace.  Lynda videos are handy as well, but the time I spend trying to learn more with AS3, I usually end up reasoning myself into the idea of becoming a better designer, and letting programmers be better programmers, not me doing both.

Comment: Bigger problem - do you know why the performance of that file is making my CPU and RAM usage go through the roof?  That swf is only loading two video files, and I have one loading nearly 30 and they both have astronomical CPU/RAM usage, so I don't think it's the amount of MB of video I'm loading...

Comment: it's not just the size of the video, it's how often you instantiate it without clearing it. every time you go a frame that has this resource it gets added, but when you add it through code, you need to remove it as-well. Essentially you created yourself a huge memory leak. AS2 takes care of this, which is why I was suggesting it. The way to go is to add and remove elements without the use of frames.